# google maps api v3 expand button

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, ionic-framework

Recently Google Maps v3 API has added a new button in my app built in Ionic which I need to remove and I did not find how to. The button expands the map.

Does anyone know how to remove that button?

[Button at the top right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MQnsQ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They also added a configuration option to control the new UI button. So when you create your map do this:

> var map = new google.maps.Map(element, {fullscreenControl: false});

see the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MapOptions).